# How can I get two different questions merged?

Tags: discussion, support, merge

There are two questions. Both have the same final problem. How to get them merged?

Also both the questions have a lot of **too localized information** that will need to be removed after the merge. What is the policy on that?

Do we edit the resulting merge question and remove unnecessary information?

[Can't boot after deleting EFI boot- and Windows-partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572558/cant-boot-after-deleting-efi-boot-and-windows-partition?rq=1)

[Accidentally deleted efi partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706414/accidentally-deleted-efi-partition)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like currently only mods are able to perform merges.

Read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107846/are-there-guidelines-on-direction-for-merging-questions-which-question-to-close)
and [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13890/merging-difficulty) for guidelines on requesting a merge:

To request a merge:

1. Flag the question and select `In need of moderator intervention` and provide links to the questions you want merged with a good and succinct reason.
2. Additionally mark the question as a duplicate.

PS: Sorry for asking this in the first place, should've searched the How To.

Comment: Forgot the question mark. I'll edit.